# Prevent Nginx from serving any files under root if no location defined

Tags: nginx

In a server block, if I have no location block defined, it seems Nginx is serving any files. For example, if the request is "/foo.html", it will serve this file if it is found under root.

Is it possible to make nginx serve files only if they match a location? A request to "/foo.html" would not work if I have not defined any location block, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define a [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) at the server level, define it only in a location block.

Answer (score 1):

Just define `location /`

```
location / {
    return 404;
}
```